# cannot set state with gatsby react Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started to use gatsby and I am simply very rusty with react. I cannot remember how to do the easiest thing properly and instead of spending another 30 minutes trying to figure out something that should be extremely easy, I figured I would ask for help.

I am new to react hooks and the older ways of doing this are simply not working. How do you set state using react hooks?

What am I doing wrong here? Why can I not set the state?  I've tried several things.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const GetImage = () => {

  const [src] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {

    fetch('http://localhost:1337/image')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(results=>{

        // console.log(results);
        //
        // this.setState({src: results})


        return results;

      })
    .then(data=>{

      console.log(data.image);

      this.setState({src: data.image})
    })

  }, [])


  return (
    <section>
      {/*<img  src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.src}`}/>*/}

      {/*<img  src={`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z/C/HgAGgwJ/lK3Q6wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`}/>*/}
    </section>
  )
}

export default GetImage
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use React functional component, you can't set state via `this` as class does. You did `useState` hook already which exports the `setState` as the 2nd value in the array returned:

```js
const [src, setSrc] = useState(0)

.then(data => {
  // set source `setSrc` above
  setSrc(data.image)
})
```